# How to run/debug java web service project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, tomcat, jakarta-ee, jboss

I have a Java Web Service project which was just handed over to me by a colleague who just resigned (no one is assisting me in my new company). Im new to Java (J2EE) and my background is .Net + frontend + azure so I am pretty much very confused with setting up and running the java project. Also, Since my background is .Net Im referencing everything with how things work in Visual Studio from running a project, setting up a project to setting up and debugging a WCF project which I realized now is very different from eclipse + java.

I would really appreciate if someone could explain to me how I can run this project which is supposedly a java web service (as I was told)?

First I have a project that is like this:
[image]

Im assuming that the project boxed as blue is the webservice (and the rest are just libraries)? Is this correct? if so how do I run and debug the project using eclipse

Second when I click on debug as -> debug on server  this is all I see:
[image]

Another colleague told me to install JBOSS (I haven't installed a server in eclipse) because that is what they used. Is there good documentation (step-by-step guide) on how to install JBOSS to run in eclipse. Im assuming that JBOSS + eclipse is like IIS express + Visual studio. Are there also other alternatives to JBOSS + eclipse like perhaps tomcat + ecplise that I can configure.

I really really find it hard to setup the java web service project in eclipse I have little to no prior experience with java j2ee programming especially with web services so any clarifications with my questions would be much appreciated. To sum up:

1. How would I really know that the project is a java webservice?
2. If so, how do I run the project and host the project using debugging in eclipse with tomcat or jboss?

I would appreciate if anyone can point me to the right direction of figuring out the source code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here we can only guide you, you will have to go through some tutorials to understand how java projects work.

Your project is a webservice project according to your web.xml file because its having context params for rest. 
the context param sets a front url to your webservice which in this case is gametime.
Check these tutorials and you will understand how it works

```
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jax-rs-tutorials/
```

Create simple examples given in the above tutorial and then you can execute your's program

Jboss is a application server which we use to run our app.

You can install jboss in eclipse or you can use it externally also.
To install eclipse and jboss you can follow the link

```
http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/java-ee/installing-jboss-tools-in-eclipse/
```

The other option is to download eclipse and jboss seperately
and use them.
Go to `jbosshome/bin`
If you download both of them seperately 
then in that case for jboss

```
Invoke the add-user.sh or add-user.bat script. ...
Choose to add a Management user. ...
Choose the realm for the user. ...
Enter the desired username and password. ...
Choose whether the user represents a remote JBoss Enterprise Application Platform 6 server instance. ...
Enter additional users. ...
Create users non-interactively.

After this go to eclipse and follow steps of below link to add jboss to eclipse

http://www.mastertheboss.com/eclipse/jboss-eclipse/jboss-and-eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

A Java web application among other things has a predefined directory structure including folders named WEB-INF, WEB-CONTENT etc.

On how to deploy a web application to Tomcat via Eclipse you can follow the steps in this [tutorial](https://eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html).